# Style not applying to nested control

Tags: xaml, winui-3

It a WinUI 3 project and im trying to set two implicit styles on all `Flyout` controls

`ShouldConstrainToRootBounds = False`

and also the same property on all `TeachingTip` controls.

The controls are nested in a Buttons Flyout

VisualStudio shows an intellisense error on the Flyout style *ShouldConstrainToRootBounds is not recognised or is not accesible*

And whilst there are no intellisense warnings for the TeachingTip style, its does not work

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultFlyoutPresenterStyle}">
        <Setter Property="ShouldConstrainToRootBounds" Value="False" /> 
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>           
    </Style>


    <Style TargetType="TeachingTip" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultTeachingTipStyle}" >
        <Setter Property="ShouldConstrainToRootBounds" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button>
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <ToggleSwitch
                        x:Name="cb_serial_flow_2"
                        IsOn="{x:Bind ViewModel.Serial, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        OffContent="Counterpart Contracts"
                        OnContent="Serial Contract" />

                    <Button
                        x:Name="btn_teach_serial_flow"
                        Click="btn_show_t_tip_serial_flow_Click">
                    </Button>

                    <TeachingTip
                        Title="Serial Contract or Counterparts?"
                        Target="{x:Bind cb_serial_flow_2}" />
                        
                </StackPanel>
```

Adding `ShouldConstrainToRootBounds = False` directly to the control works fine, ie

```
<Flyout ShouldConstrainToRootBounds="False">

<TeachingTip
    ShouldConstrainToRootBounds="False"
    Title="Serial Contract or Counterparts?"
    Target="{x:Bind cb_serial_flow_2}" />
```

But they dont work using the implicit style in Resources

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `Flyout` doesn't have `Style` property.

If you need to do this with `Style` anyway, you could consider using `Popup` instead. But then you'll need to implement some behaviors to fill the gap between `Flyout` and `Popup`.

So, I'd go with setting `ShouldConstrainToRootBounds` directly.

BTW, this is not directly related to this question but there's an old ongoing [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1035) about styling `Flyout`s in `UserControl`s. Just so you know.

Comment: Thanks for your help again :-) Yeah ive applied directly, I was trying to save a bit of time with a style but there you go, WPF seemed almost ready when realeased, oh to dream :-) I love WinUI 3 though!

Comment: Difficult times but I also love and enjoy WinUI 3. :-) If this answers your question, please accept it as the answer so we can close this session.

Comment: No worries, ive upvoted but im gonna leave it open in case someone comes up with a  workaround, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Could yo please tell us which version of WindowsAppSDK are you using?

I suggest you could try to updated to the latest (WindowsAppSDK 1.4).

`ShouldConstrainToRootBounds="False"`doesn't work in winui 3 until Windows AppSDK 1.4.

For more details I suggest you could refer to the Github:https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5958

Comment: Im using 1.4 `ShouldConstrainToRootBounds="False"` works if I place it directly on the `Flyout` or `TeachingTip` but not via the implicit style

Comment: Edited the question to add clarity

Comment: I suggest you could post the issue to the [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues) for better help.